# Cakephp : AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cakephp

My cakephp application is giving me this error:

```
[Tue Oct 16 14:31:10.079872 2018] [core:error] [pid 30667] [client ::1:56973] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://localhost/carte_drin/index.php
```

I configured my .htaccess this way:

**/www/ :**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**www/carte_drin/app :**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

**www/carte-drin/app/webroot :**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I uncommented this statement in core.php:

```
 Configure::write('App.baseUrl', '/carte_drin/');
```

And the error is persisting.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong? Your answers and eventual helps are welcome.

Best

Comment: You might look into how to get Apache to log redirect details; seeing exactly what it's doing, and how that changes as you tweak the .htaccess file, can be very illuminating.

Comment: Actually I added this line at each .htaccess file :     RewriteBase /carte_drin. Some images, css are loaded but the problem still occurs. At www folder, this line makes all the projects in the server point on the application. I need something to adjust the right access to the server.